# Istikharah approach to pick right option from the three options

Tags: istikharah

Folks,

I have three choices & I need to pick one for a professional life.

So how do I utilize Istikharah to pick the best one & move forward? & at the same give sincere devotion after picking the right one & not giving thoughts in other two fields.

Comment: There are lots of questions on the topic of istikhara already. And there's only one way how to do Istikhara.

Comment: I knew there is a single way to perform Istikharah (Before deciding a single purpose or vision) but what if the person has to pick the best from the three. @Medi1Saif

Comment: If I had three choices A, B and C, then I'd do istikhara for A or (B or C), and if the result is the latter then do a second istikhara for B or C.

Comment: You need to do only one istekharah, imagine you got 3 offers of employment. You speak to good muslims which offer is best and do istekharah. Adjust the dua of istekharah accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

All fatwas I've consulted do not disagree to the procedure provided in comments:

You may add do Istikhara for many options A or B or C etc. or A and B or B and C etc.

So based on the known hadith (See for example in [Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/97/19)) you may change the wording from:

> ...فَإِنْ كُنْتَ تَعْلَمُ هَذَا الأَمْرَ ـ ثُمَّ تُسَمِّيهِ بِعَيْنِهِ ـ خَيْرًا لِي فِي عَاجِلِ أَمْرِي وَآجِلِهِ ـ قَالَ أَوْ فِي دِينِي وَمَعَاشِي وَعَاقِبَةِ أَمْرِي ـ فَاقْدُرْهُ لِي، وَيَسِّرْهُ لِي،   ...
> O Allah If You know It this matter (name your matter) is good for me both at present and in the future, (or in my religion), in my this life and in the Hereafter, then fulfill it for me and make it easy for me,

to

> اللَّهُمَّ فَإِنْ كُنْتَ تَعْلَمُ هَذَا الأَمْرَ "أ" أو الأَمْرَ "ب" أو... ـ ثُمَّ تُسَمِّيهِ بِعَيْنِهِ ـ خَيْرًا لِي فِي عَاجِلِ أَمْرِي وَآجِلِهِ ـ قَالَ أَوْ فِي دِينِي وَمَعَاشِي وَعَاقِبَةِ أَمْرِي ـ فَاقْدُرْهُ لِي، وَيَسِّرْهُ لِي،
> O Allah If You know It the matter "A" or the matter "B" or ... (name your matter) is good for me both at present and in the future, (or in my religion), in my this life and in the Hereafter, then fulfill it for me and make it easy for me,

Further it is permissible to ask for different matters at once in one Istikharah: Such as marriage, job offer, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helps.